# Confused about xxHash

Tags: javascript, node.js, hash

I'm using xxHash to create hashes from elements id. I just don't want to show real id on website. I created script to test is there option to get same hashes:

```
const _ = require('lodash');
const XXH = require('xxhashjs');

let hashes = []
let uniq_hashes = []

for(let i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
    var h = XXH.h32(i.toString(), 0xABCD).toString(16)
    hashes.push(h)
}

uniq_hashes = _.uniq(hashes)
console.log(hashes.length, uniq_hashes.length);
```

Log from the script is `1000000 999989`, so some hashes was the same. Is it correct way how xxHash works?

Also, first pair is '1987' and '395360'

If i need really unique hashes (no crypto) what should I use?

Comment: Using `XXH.h64` variant will considerably reduce collision probabilities. See http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/ .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the birthday paradox you should see a collisions at around 1:16^2 or 10^6 / 2^16 = ~15 so 11 collisions seems about right. (Note: the math is grossly simplified, see [Birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for good math.)

Too reduce the number of collisions increase the hash size and use a cryptographic hash such as SHA-256. Cryptographic hash functions are designed to avoid collisions.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a hash with a larger hash digest. Even a 32-bit chunk of a secure cryptographic hash will have unavoidable collisions eventually.

Since you are using Node.js and want something faster than cryptographic hashes, try [MetroHash128](https://github.com/robertklep/node-metrohash) or [murmur128](https://github.com/hideo55/node-murmurhash3) or [CityHash128](https://github.com/fbzhong/node-cityhash). There's also CityHash256 is you want to go completely overboard. These should be very fast due to using C++ bindings, and the chance of random collision is reduced astronomically.